# how to show more information in wso2 apim GeoLocation based analytics?

Tags: wso2, api-manager

I configured geo location based statistics according to the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/analyzing-apim-statistics-with-batch-analytics/using-geo-location-based-statistics/configuring-geo-location-based-statistics/) for api manager and it worked perfectly.but it only shows the country name and count:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdljK.png)

I want to show for example the city,ip,time zone etc.
but how i can do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default geolocation widget is showing only the country based API invocations only. In order to support custom information, a custom widget is required. Currently in the database level count against city and country is there. But it shows count against country only. You can add country and city view to the widget by doing customization to the widget.
In order to support timezone, maybe you can keep the city/country to timezone mapping in the UI and render it on the chart.